# Google app engine gives me 400 bad request status code?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urllib

In google appengine:

```
urlfetch.fetch('http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_text_outline&chld=000000|12|h|FFFFFF|_|Tested: 21 Dec') works fine.
```

But when i do this way:

```
text = 'Tested: 21 Dec'  // This ia a variable
my_url = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_text_outline&chld=000000|12|h|FFFFFF|_|'+text
urlfetch.fetch(my_url)
```

Now this gives `400 error`. What I realize that this is not recognizing characters after `|`  . So, this makes call to only `'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_text_outline&chld=000000|`

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is this your exact code? If so, could you print my_url before `urlfetch.fetch()`ing it in the second example? It seems to me that it should be the same as your first example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the problem, but you should encode your strings before constructing url with them:

```
import urllib
text = urllib.quote_plus('Tested: 21 Dec')  // This ia a variable
my_url = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_text_outline&chld=000000|12|h|FFFFFF|_|%s' % text
urlfetch.fetch(my_url)
```

Also in most cases it is better practice to use string formatting `'... %s' % (a,b)` or `''.join([a, b])` instead of `a + b`.